# Allow One User to Edit A Field

Tags: page-layout, field-level-security

Our business rules require that the opportunity probability field be linked to the Opportunity's stage.  Users can choose the stage, which automatically updates the probability, but the probability field is locked (via page layout "read-only" setting) so that they can't make manual changes.

We now have a single user, working on a special project, who should be able to manually tweak the probabilities for her opportunities, but I can't figure out a way to make the field be editable for her while being locked for everyone else.  **I want to avoid making a separate page layout for her, because there are 5 record types, each with its own page layout, which would mean 5 duplicate page layouts**

Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use permission sets.

1. For all users, set their profiles to have that field be read-only
2. Create a permission set that has that field read/write.
3. Make the field editable on the page layout.
4. Assign the PermissionSet to that user.

Voila!

Comment: Is this the relevant / matching documentation? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_fields